# Binding textbox to multiple selected items in listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, listbox, multipleselection

I have two classes:

```
Class classA
{
   int intA { get; set; }
   classB B { get; set; }
}
Class classB
{
   int intB { get; set; }
}
```

The `ListBox` is binded to `ObservableCollection` from classA

```
public ObservableCollection<classA> listItems = new ObservableCollection<classA>();
itemsListBox.ItemsSource = listItems;
```

The `ListBox`is using `SelecteMode="Extended"`.
Now, I have another textbox that is binded to the `SelectedItem` in the itemsListBox:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElemantName=itemsListBox, Path=SelectedItem.B.intB}"/>
```

Everything here works fine but when I'm trying to edit the textbox when multiple items are selected in the listbox. Only the first selecteditem is being changed.

Any idea how can I fix it?

Comment: Not entirely sure I understand your problem.

Comment: If i'm selecting 2 items in the listbox, and writing "hello" in the textbox, I want that both listItems[0].B.intB and listItems[1].B.intB will be "hello".
listItem[0] and listItem[1] is just an example, I want it to be the int of the selectedItem

Comment: `SelectedItem` will only return a single item, so that is the expected behavior. `SelectedItems` returns the list of all items selected. You probably will want to use either a `PropertyChange` notification on your `TextBox.Text` bound property, or some code behind, to properly update the text of all `SelectedItems`

Comment: Did you consider just using a TextView with ItemTemplate and TextBox so you can just edit in the list?

Comment: @Rachel I tried it with intA but I get the error that intA property not found on object 'SelectedItemCollection'.

Comment: @Blam yes there is some reason that I need to do it that way. There are lots of other parameters and textboxes so we need it to be outside that listbox

Comment: @amirm `SelectedItems` returns a list of objects, and `List<object>` does not have a property called `intA`. You need to cast each item in the `SelectedItems` list to `classA` in order to access to that property

Comment: @Rachel thanks for the help and sorry for the noob questions. I'll try to come up with something and if i'll have problem i'll update.